# React-Konva canvas resizing

Tags: reactjs, react-konva, konva

I would like to be able to resize the height of the whole konva canvas/stage like we are able to do with canvas objects like shapes/images with the help of transformer. Is there something already in place for the same?

Comment: Why do you need that? What is your use case?

Comment: The idea is to resize them to a desired height so that something else can be added between multiple canvases.